# I need to remove rows from a query based on two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I need the results to be suppressed/removed under two conditions.

```
     SELECT
      CompanyID, 
      CustomerID, 
      Type,
      CustomerCode, 
      CustomerType, 
      CaseRank
     FROM Table
     ORDER BY CaseRank
```

I need to remove any rows that have a Type of "TypeA" AND a CaseRank that's not equal to 1.

Comment: Did you ever use `WHERE`?

Comment: I did use a WHERE statement initially, assuming this would work, but it hasn't: WHERE Type = ''TypeA" AND CaseRank <> 1

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT
  CompanyID, 
  CustomerID, 
  Type,
  CustomerCode, 
  CustomerType, 
  CaseRank
 FROM Table
 WHERE NOT (Type='TypeA' AND CaseRank != 1)
 ORDER BY CaseRank
```

Comment: This did it. I wasn't even aware of a WHERE NOT statement. Thank you!

Comment: @DPool34 . . . There is no `WHERE NOT` statement.  There is a `WHERE` clause and a boolean `NOT` operator.